# Multiple html files in fragment using webView via ListView

Tags: android, listview, webview, fragment

I created a webview application with listview in fragment.
I followed this link:
[Opening multiple local html files using webView via ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26244567/opening-multiple-local-html-files-using-webview-via-listview)
When I click on the item it should redirect me to the detail of the webview item.
Now i am trying to implement it in fragment But only one item is successful while the other items do not point me to the webview detail that should be.
I've been looking for a solution but still no luck.
Here is my code

MainActivity:

```
package com.listviewfragment.withsublist;

import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Main_listFragment main_listFragment = new Main_listFragment();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction =  getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
      fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.content, main_listFragment);
      fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }
 }
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.listviewfragment.withsublist.MainActivity">

<FrameLayout
android:id="@+id/content"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"></FrameLayout>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Main_listFragment.java

```
package com.listviewfragment.withsublist;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;


/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 */
public class Main_listFragment extends Fragment {
ListView listView;


public Main_listFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main_list, container, false);
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.list);
    String[] values = new String[] {
            "Detail Webview 1",
            "Detail Webview 2",
            "Detail Webview 3",
    };

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, values);

    // Assign adapter to ListView
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    // ListView Item Click Listener
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                int position, long id) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            // ListView Clicked item value
            listView.getItemAtPosition(position);
            if (position == 0) {
                Detail_webview_mainFragment dlm = new Detail_webview_mainFragment ();
                getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content, dlm).addToBackStack(null).commit();
            }
            else if (position == 1) {
                Detail_webview_mainFragment dlm = new Detail_webview_mainFragment ();
                getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content, dlm).addToBackStack(null).commit();
            }
            else if (position == 2) {
                Detail_webview_mainFragment dlm = new Detail_webview_mainFragment ();;
                getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content, dlm).addToBackStack(null).commit();
            }
        }

    });
    return rootView;
 }

}
```

fragment_main_list.xml

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.listviewfragment.withsublist.Main_listFragment">


    <ListView
       android:id="@+id/list"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent">

    </ListView>

</FrameLayout>
```

Detail_webview_mainFragment.java

```
package com.listviewfragment.withsublist;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;


/**
* A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
*/
public class Detail_webview_mainFragment extends Fragment {
WebView view;

public Detail_webview_mainFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    //getArguments().getString("key");
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_detail_webview_main, container, false);

    view = (WebView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.webview);
    // Enable Javascript
    WebSettings webSettings = view.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    view.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

    int pos = getActivity().getIntent().getIntExtra("key", 0);
    if (pos == 0) {
        view.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/html/webview1.html");
    } else if (pos == 1) {
        view.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/html/webview2.html");
    } else if (pos == 2) {
        view.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/html/webview3.html");
    }
    return rootView;

   }
}
```

fragment_detail_webview_main

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.listviewfragment.withsublist.Detail_webview_mainFragment">

<!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
<WebView
android:id="@+id/webview"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"></WebView>

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Why do you want to use fragment instead of Activity? By using Detail_webview_mainFragment to replace your MainActivity layout it means that the List Fragment will also disappear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using same detail fragment for all position 0,1,2. Just do like this:

```
Detail_webview_mainFragment dlm = new Detail_webview_mainFragment ();
Bundle args = new Bundle();
args.putInt("key", pos);
dlm.setArguments(args);
```

and instead of

```
int pos = getActivity().getIntent().getIntExtra("key", 0);
```

in detail fragment do :

```
int pos=0;
if (getArguments() != null) {       
 pos= getArguments().getInt("key");             
}
```